# Rooting BQ Aquaris M10 tablet?

Tags: permissions, root, tablet, arm, aquaris

With Ubuntu, i think the root access is essential, just like ability to remove any "cloud" apps, like automatic update checks or stuff like crash reports etc.

Should i buy [this tablet](http://www.ubuntu.com/tablet/devices) if i need:

1. **Root access** (without 3rdparty tools) to modify any system file, to crash or damage device/boot, flash it and etc.
2. **Remove any vendor software**, disable GPS.

Reading this [blog post](http://blog.afandian.com/2016/04/i-got-a-bq-aquaris-m10-ubuntu-tablet/) i see:

> Once I got it I could look around, but there’s no touching. The root
>   partition is mounted as read-only so there’s no way to install
>   anything with apt-get. You can re-mount the root partition in
>   read-write mode (I’ve not tried this) but it’s incompatible with
>   getting software updates. I suppose I can grudgingly accept that this
>   was a reasonable technical solution for mobile software, but they
>   could have made at least minimal effort to allow me to install
>   packages at the same time.

3. **Terminal with `ssh`, `openvpn`, `python3` and `pip3`**, i need for my activity
4. I understand there's an ARM-based processor and there're no repositories for ARM in APT, but i am wondering if can compile C++ right on it, so at least, i can always reinvent my own wheel for something? How can i actually get `g++` working or it's there?

There is a lack of such information about this tablet.

Answer (score 2):

Temporarly enabling r/w does not disable system updates I have tried it:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw
```

The Important thing to remember is that updates are based on a diffrence between images so this will likely cause some changes you do to be wiped or break after update (or worse, thus the scare and warning you might need to reflash) but in practice just installing ssh or another terminal utility should work fine.

Also `apt` works fine out of box once making the file system writable (tested on my mx4 and my m10), and there are arm repositories. I have installed things like fish shell and silversearcher for the terminal on mine, the only problem left is the size of the root partition to install extra stuff.

Comment: also this is a thing: http://i.stack.imgur.com/1rFTC.png they have a app that can install ppa's, software from the repisitories, deb's, ect - amazing things are coming, just still in the works.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes - root access and read/write system is easy to achieve. There seem to
   be multiple methods, but the one I used was the `android-gadget-service enable
   writable` command from the tablet. (source: [this blog
   post](http://www.cnx-software.com/2016/04/30/setup-guide-mini-review-of-bq-aquaris-m10-ubuntu-edition-tablet-from-a-developers-perspective/))

About updates while system is writable - I have automatic updates turned off,
but it was able to update to OTA11 with the system still writable and no apparent
problems.

2. Not sure about that, but with full root access it should be
   possible. The third party apps that come pre-installed can be uninstalled as
   well.
3. and 4. Yes no problem. Once the system is writable you can install pretty much
   anything. There is a decent terminal app on the Ubuntu store (from memory it
   was preinstalled too). There are plenty of repositories preconfigured with
   loads of programs available - at
   least I was able to install python3, pip3, ruby, tmux, vim, gcc, etc... SSH is
   built in and just needs enabling. It's
   pretty easy to add ppa's for other programs too (I installed syncthing and neovim). 
   See [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUIgo.png) for an example of web development on the m10.

There's definitely not much information, agreed (unless you really dig around or ask
lots of questions). If you haven't already, I'd recommend the #ubuntu-touch
channel on freenode irc for discussions/questions with other users and
developers.